# iOS button not appearing on head

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6.1

This isn't a difficult question, but i cannot find any help with this.
Placing a button on a iOS Storyboard in the header (navigation bar).
Below is what a regular button placed on their displays as (yes, it has text).
When using a bar button, it only places it on the bottom of the view where it cannot be seen.

I tried doing it via code, and it displayed correctly but then had issues with correctly segue'ing to the next view.
All i'm after is a button on the top right, Why is this so difficult?
[image]

Comment: What is your tint color on your bar? Its probably there, but you can't see it because the font tint color is the same as the back bar.

Comment: Your button's minimum y position should be > 64.0 px..

Comment: the coloring is fine, it literraly goes behind as if there were a z-index

Comment: The thing is your design is fine, you just need to turn off the Top Navigation Bar for ViewController, because you actually don't need it while designing, the navigation bar will appear automatically if the root is navigation controller.

Comment: @iphonic so the 64px above is unusable for custom?

Comment: @Simon. What does your document outline look like?